# Redeclare random() error

Tags: php

I'm basically trying to include a php file on my index.php file for my usersystem. But I've ran into an error. This is the code I used:

```
<?php include("usersystem/index.php"); ?>
```

**Error:**

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare random() (previously declared in
>   /home/public_html/upload.php:2) in /homepublic_html/global.php on line
>   35

**Upload.php**: http://pastebin.com/YcJYF2hb
global.php on line 35 I have: `}`, part of the file is at http://pastebin.com/gMsiPa7Z

I don't understand what's going on?

Comment: The error isn't exactly cryptic, you can't declare 2 functions with the same name in PHP. Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147614/same-named-function-with-multiple-arguments-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare two functions with the same name. Both the snippets included above contains   a function named random defined. I suggest that you rename them to be more specific.